# I have a class Task and I want to save memory and efficiency, should I use __slots__?

Tags: python, queue, slots

this is my class:

```py
class Task:
    __slots__ = ('callback', 'args')
    def __init__(self, callback: 'Callable', *args):
        self.callback = callback
        self.args = args

    def execute(self):
        try:
            self.callback(*self.args)
        except BaseException:
            print(traceback.print_exc())
```

I have a thread that consumes a queue of these tasks:

```py
def check_queue_tasks(self):
        while self.running:
            Tasks.queue.get()
            Tasks.get_task().execute()
            Tasks.remove_task()
            Tasks.queue.task_done()
```

I have several scripts that create tasks and push them to the queue, so in the life of this program thousands of tasks could be created that of course will die when they are executed.

The key question is, should I use **slots** for this class? does this save memory? improves the speed in the execution of tasks in the queue? or does it just make it worse for this case?

Comment: Have you performance tested it?

Comment: It will save memory, but in terms of speed it likely won't a huge difference, although attribute access should be faster, but that is probably not a bottleneck to begin with